# "Move Property" button missing in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to move a Google Analytics property to another account.

I'm following this guide:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6370521?hl=en

However the 'Move Property' button isn't listed - it just has 'Move to Trash Can'

How can I do this? I can find nothing about this missing button in Google - all tutorials say you must press it.[image]

Comment: That's odd... the path is /admin/property/move, if you click into "property settings" it should say "/admin/property/settings". Just try replacing settings with "move"?

Comment: Did you check your permissions on that account ("Manage Users" and "Edit") ?

Comment: maybe it's a permissions thing - unfortunately it's hard for me to check (for long boring reasons) - so I fixed this in another way.

Comment: @niico how did you fix it then?

Answer (score 2):

It is your permissions, you need account level permissions to manage accounts/properties like moving them. Some account above you has the original owners rights which means only that account can give your account access.